Installing Electron on Ubuntu
so i wanted to learn a bit of electron frontend development and worked myself through the installation guide on the electron site.
Everything works well, until the npm install electron --save-dev command.
Also tried if with sudo npm install electron --save-dev, but i get the same output.
Here's the error message:
$ npm install electron --save-dev
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/marc/electron_app/node_modules/electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! /home/marc/electron_app/node_modules/electron/install.js:45
npm ERR!   checksums: process.env.electron_use_remote_checksums ?? process.env.npm_config_electron_use_remote_checksums ? undefined : require('./checksums.json'),
npm ERR!                                                         ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
npm ERR!     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
npm ERR!     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/marc/.npm/_logs/2024-07-10T09_35_16_070Z-debug-0.log


It seems like the problem has something to do with the two ? in the  command npm executes, but i have no idea how to fix that. Nodejs is correctly installed.

What's in the complete log?

@tripleee https://pastebin.com/9GDf7gWj  created a pastebin with the log, since it's over 400 lines long

I had the same issue. The reason for this is the outdated version of nodejs and npm in Ubuntu that is not compatible with electron. You need to use a version according to: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/electron-timelines
(you can check your own versions via "node -v" and "npm -v")
To update node you can use:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
For updating npm you can use
npm install -g npm@latest


THank you kindly! Much more helpful than https://github.com/electron/electron/issues
